# XSLT for XML to text

Tags: xml, xslt

I have never used XSLT but I need it to transform an XML document (Swedish language corpus) to text. The XML looks like this:

```
<corpus id="bloggmix2014">
<blog url="http://thaipinnen.blogg.se/" title="thaipinnen" age="19" city="Södertälje" categories="|Mode och design &gt; Mode, allmänt|Mode och design &gt; Webbdesign|Musik &gt; Allmänt och övrigt|Vardagsbetraktelser &gt; Ingen ålder|">
<text title="Summerburst day 1" date="2014-06-14" tags="|" datefrom="20140614" dateto="20140614" timefrom="000000" timeto="235959">
<sentence id="934b7396b8-934befce19">
<w pos="UO" msd="UO" lemma="|" lex="|" saldo="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="1" dephead="" deprel="ROOT">Summerburst</w>
<w pos="UO" msd="UO" lemma="|" lex="|" saldo="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="2" dephead="1" deprel="HD">day</w>
<w pos="RG" msd="RG.NOM" lemma="|1|" lex="|_1..nl.1|" saldo="|en..1|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="3" dephead="4" deprel="DT">1</w>
<w pos="NN" msd="NN.UTR.SIN.IND.NOM" lemma="|" lex="|" saldo="|" prefix="|hotell..nn.1|" suffix="|frukost..nn.1|" ref="4" dephead="1" deprel="MS">hotellfrukost</w>
<w pos="IN" msd="IN" lemma="|godmorgon|" lex="|godmorgon..in.1|" saldo="|god_morgon..1|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="5" dephead="4" deprel="ET">Godmorgon</w>
<w pos="MAD" msd="MAD" lemma="|" lex="|" saldo="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" ref="6" dephead="4" deprel="IU">!</w>
</sentence>
</text>
</blog>
</corpus>
```

So as you can see there are a lot of attributes etc. I don't care about these attributes. I just want the string (if that's what you call them)
of each word tag to be in my document, separated by new lines. So this excerpt would look like this transformed to text:

```
Summerburst
day
1
hotellfrukost
Godmorgon
!
```

Comment: You're  not new here: you know that's no way to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

An **XSLT 2.0** solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="//w" separator="&#10;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An **XSLT 1.0** solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//w"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="w">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```